# Does a geometric series from an $o(x)$ function converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $f(x)$ is positive, increasing, and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{|x|} = 0$. For some $a \in (0,1)$ and for any $x>0$, does the infinite series $\sum^{\infty}_{i=0} a^i f\left(\frac{x}{a^i}\right)$ converge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No, not always.

Counterexample: consider 
$$
f(x)=|x|/\log(1+|x|),
$$ 
then $x\mapsto f(x)$ is increasing on $x\gt0$, $f(x)/|x|\to0$ when $|x|\to\infty$ and 
$$
a^if(x/a^i)=|x|/\log(1+|x|/a^i)\sim g(x)/i
$$ 
when $i\to\infty$, with $g(x)=|x|/\log(1/a)$.

For every $x\ne0$, $g(x)\ne0$ hence the series $\sum\limits_ia^if(x/a^i)$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Use $n$th term test to say is the series converge then the $\lim a_n=0$. Here we have, $\lim a_n*f(\frac{x}{a^i})=\lim a_n \frac{f(x)}{f(a^i)}$. We are now granted that both converge since $a\in(0,1)$, and thus a geometric series. By supposition, lim $a_n* \frac{f(x)}{f(a^i)}=\lim a_n *\frac{f(x)}{f(|a^i|)}$ = $(\lim a_n)(\lim \frac{f(x)}{f(|a^i|)}$) (since $a^i$ is already positive, abs value doesn't change it, and if both limits exists then product of $\lim$ is $\lim$ of product). Well both go to $0$ so $(\lim a_n)(\lim \frac{f(x)}{f(|a^i|)})=0*0=0$, thus the series converges.